# Proper application of Surface Area of Revolution formulae?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, surfaces

I'm a little confused about how to properly apply the integrals used to calculate the area of a surface of revolution.

Find the exact area of the surface obtained by rotating the curve about the x-axis: $y^2 = x + 1, 0 \le x \le 3$

Rewriting the equation, I have $y= \sqrt{x+1}$. Taking its derivative yields $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}$. Substituting these values into what I believe is the appropriate formula, I have (some steps in the algebra omitted for conciseness):

$$S = \int_0^32\pi y\sqrt{1+(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}})^2} dx = 2\pi\int_0^3\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4(x+1)}} dx = 2\pi\int_0^3\sqrt{\frac{4x+5}{4}}$$

Which eventually simplifies to $\pi\int_0^3\sqrt{4x+5}dx$. Applying u-substitution then gets me

$$\frac{\pi}{4}\int_5^{17}(u)^\frac{1}{2}du = \frac{\pi}{6}(17\sqrt{17} - 5\sqrt{5})$$

Which differs from my textbook's (Stewart's Calculus, 8th ed.) answer:

$$\frac{\pi}{6}(27\sqrt{27} - 5\sqrt{5})$$

What did I do wrong? When I saw that my answer was the same except for that $27\sqrt{27}$, I assumed I'd made some mistake in my algebra somewhere, but I've looked over my work three times now and I can't seem to find any.

Comment: You probably didn't convert your bounds correctly (because that's where your 17s came from, and they have 27s in their place).

Comment: Book answer may very well be a typo...

Comment: The limits look fine to me based on the $x$ bounds and the chosen $u.$  I wonder if the book has a typo because $\sqrt{27}$ can be simplified, and IIRC Stewart's calc usually simplifies those answers.